# How do I remove the specific assumptions in the proof of the rank theorem in the special case of injective differential?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

I have the following proof in my notes. It is a particular case of the more general rank theorem.

Theorem (Rank theorem for injective differential). Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold  of dimension $m$, and that $N$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Suppose $F : M \to N$ is smooth. Let $p \in M$. If $dF_p$ is injective, then there are charts $(U, \varphi)$ of M around p and $(V,\psi )$ of N around $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$
and for all $x \in\varphi(U)$, and

$\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{−1}(x) = (x, 0_{n−m})$

**Proof**

We prove the theorem **in the case** that $M$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$, $N$ open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, $p = 0_m$ and $F(p) = 0_n$ By using appropriate charts around p and F(p), we can prove the general case.

Suppose $dF_p$ is injective. Then $m \le n$. Define $Q: M \to \Bbb R^m$ and
$R: M \to \Bbb R^{n−m}$ by $F(x) = (Q(x), R(x))$ for $x \in M$.

Since $DF(p)$ is injective, its matrix has an $m × m$ invertible submatrix. We can do this by possibly exchanging coordinates ensuring that $DQ(p)$ is such a matrix; we will assume this from now on. Because $DQ(p)$ is invertible, then due to the inverse function theorem there are nbhs $U$ of $p$ and $\tilde V$ of $Q(p)$ such that $\varphi := Q|_U : U \to\tilde V$ is a diffeomorphism

Define  $V := \tilde V \times \Bbb R^{n−m}$.This is an open nbhd of $F(p) = 0_n$, because $Q(p) = 0_m$.

Define :$ \psi:V \to \Bbb R^n: \psi(v; w) = (v, w − R \circ \varphi^{−1}(v))$, for $v \in \tilde V$ and $w \in \Bbb R^{n−m}$.

This is a diffeomorphism onto its image, with inverse given by

$\psi^{−1}(s, t) = (s, t + \varphi^{−1}(s))$, for $s \in \Bbb R^m $ and $t \in \Bbb R^{n−m}$ such that $(s, t) \in \psi(V )$.

And for all $x \in \varphi(U)$,

$\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{−1}(x) =\psi(x,R\circ\varphi^{-1}(x))= (x, 0_{n−m}) \tag{*}$

**I have a couple of doubts**

1. How does one come up a priori with the idea to define  $\psi$ like that? It is supposed to be a chart of $ N$ around $F(p)$, so how does one know that it has that form?
2. How do I prove  the general case ? (that is removing the assumptions: $M$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$, $N$ open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, $p = 0_m$ and $F(p) = 0_n$ but still considering injective derivative)I am having trouble writting it down. Moreover why are they using charts in the proof above if they are not working with general manifolds?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: This is a local theorem, and locally everything about manifolds reduces to open subsets of Euclidean space. The idea comes from linearizing: Up to linear changes of coordinates, an injective linear map is the standard inclusion of $\Bbb R^m$ into $\Bbb R^n$ as the slice $x_{n-m+1}=\dots=x_n=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I take you're talking about question 1, how is this expression $\psi(v, w) =(v, w − R \circ \varphi^{−1}(v))$ supposed to be a sort of linearization of (I guess F or $\psi$?)? I am trying to write down a Taylor expansion but I am not getting this expresion. Your comment does help to realize that I separate \psi in two components$\psi(v, w) =(v,\tilde w)$ with dimensions m and n-m, but I don't see how $\tilde w= w − R \circ \varphi^{−1}(v) $

Answer (score 1):

The proof is awkwardly written and obscures the central ideas. We assume that we’re in Euclidean soace and the derivative at $p=0$ is $\begin{bmatrix} I\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Consider the map $g(x,y)=F(x)+(0,y)$. The inverse function theorem gives a local inverse $\tau$ for $g$. Then look at $(\tau\circ g)(x,0)=(\tau\circ F)(x)$.

Comment: Are you proving it using the posted proof as starting point? Cause I don't see how you are using it to generatlize the proof. Or are you suggesting a whole new proof from scratch? How does the assumption about the derivative that you are introducing does not make the proof lose generality?

Comment: I find the given proof obscures matters, so, yes, I’m giving a separate argument that makes things motivated and clear. You can then see how to give the “slick” argument using this if you have to. By choosing a standard form you do not lose generality. This preliminary linear change of coordinates becomes part of the nice chart, ultimately. Work that detail out carefully. You will see this hundreds of times working in analysis and with manifolds.

Comment: But you proposal has the same assumptions as the posted proof right? Euclidean spaces, and $p=0$ ( except for F(0)=0 maybe ) plus a new assumption. Assuming this proves the theorem for this assumptions now I am back at the root of my question: how to remove all this assumptions.

Comment: Why do you want to remove steps that simplify and clarify the argument? You seem to think you have sacrificed “generality.” The result is as general as it can be.

Comment: How is it general if both proofs prove the theorem for particular things?for euclidean spaces instead of general manifolds and for p=0 instead of a general p (plus for derivative equal to the $[I,0]^T$) in your case. And in any of the proofs the question remains once proven with these assumptions, how to go from that to the general case, otherwise I can't see how generality is not sacrified. I don't see either why this clarifies and symplifies anything. Also the given proof makes assumptions to symplify and does not explain how to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

See [Product manifolds in Dieudonné, Vol. 3: Reduction of proofs to open sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4171051/568204) for some indications of how to handle such reductions.

Just to be super explicit for this question, suppose you prove the rank theorem for injective differentials in your given special case. For completely general $F:M\to N$,

- fix a point $p\in M$ about which we’re going to prove things.
- fix an arbitrary chart $(V_0,\psi_0)$ in $N$ around $F(p)$, and consider the translation $\tau_1:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ given by $\tau_1(y)=y-\psi_1(F(p))$ (translations are obviously diffeomorphisms). Now, define $V_1=V_0$, and $\psi_1=\tau_1\circ\psi_0$. Then, $(V_1,\psi_1)$ is a chart for $N$ around the point $F(p)$, and furthermore, $\psi_1(F(p))=0\in\Bbb{R}^n$.
- fix an arbitrary chart $(U_0,\phi_0)$ in $M$ around $p$. and consider the translation $\tau_0:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^m$ given by $\tau(x)=x-\phi_0(p)$ (obviously a diffeomorphism). Now, define $U_1=U_0\cap F^{-1}(V_0)$ (so that we can compose things later) and $\phi_1=\tau_0\circ\phi_0|_{U_1}$. Then, $(U_1,\phi_1)$ is still a chart for $M$ around the point $p$, and furthermore, $\phi_1(p)=0\in\Bbb{R}^m$.
- Now, define the **local representative** $f:=\psi_1\circ F\circ\phi_1^{-1}:\phi_1[U_1]\subset\Bbb{R}^m\to \psi_1[V_1]\subset\Bbb{R}^m$. This map is $F$ composed on the domain and target by charts, so $f$ is a smooth map between open subsets of cartesian spaces; also all our translations and stuff ensure that $f(0_{\Bbb{R}^m})=0_{\Bbb{R}^n}$.
- We are now in the perfect position to apply our special case to the map $f$. We find that there exist diffeomorphisms $\widetilde{\phi}:\widetilde{U}_1\subset\phi_1[U_1]\to \widetilde{U}_2\subset\Bbb{R}^m$ and $\widetilde{\psi}\subset V_1\subset\psi_1[V_1]\to\widetilde{V}_2\subset\Bbb{R}^n$, where $\widetilde{U}_1,\widetilde{V}_1$ are respective open neighborhoods of $0$, and $\widetilde{U}_2,\widetilde{V}_2$ are open, such that $\widetilde{\psi}\circ f\circ\widetilde{\phi}^{-1}$ has the desired canonical form $x\mapsto (x,0)$.
- now, re-track everything. The desired chart about $p$ is $(U,\phi)$, where $U=\phi_1^{-1}[\widetilde{U}]$, and $\phi:=\widetilde{\phi}\circ \phi_1|_U$. Likewise, the desired chart about $F(p)$ is $(V,\psi)$ where $V=\psi_1^{-1}[\widetilde{V}]$ and $\psi:=\widetilde{\psi}\circ\psi_1|_{V}$. A little unwinding shows that $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}=\widetilde{\psi}\circ f\circ \widetilde{\phi}^{-1}: x\mapsto (x,0)$.

So, you see the reason nobody ever says all of this is because it is first of all annoying (I really hope I don’t have any typos above), because all we’re doing is suitably shrinking open sets on the domain/target, and composing on the domain/target by appropriate diffeomorphisms. Both of these ‘operations’ do not change whether or not we have a chart for our manifold. That’s why we simply say ‘without loss of generality’. Also, the notation very quickly gets out of hand.

But really, I strongly urge you to convince yourself of these arguments. Making these simplifications should be the first thing in any complicated proof. In fact, the proof also made another simplifying assumption about the derivative having such and such block format. More precisely, this means we need to compose $\psi_1$ and $\phi_0$ by suitable invertible linear transformations (which encapsulate the appropriate row/column operations)… but I’m not going to type that out as well. Anyway, see also [Trying to understand the statement of Rudin's Rank Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4485741/568204)

---

“Another” way of saying all of this is:

1. the theorem holds for $F$ if and only if for all open $U_0\subset M,V_0\subset N$, it holds for $F|_{U_0\to V_0}:U_0\to V_0$. This is then equivalent to the theorem holding for all $U,V$ which are domains of chart maps (because chart domains are open in the manifolds, and conversely for every open set in the manifold, and every point in the open set, there exist chart domains completely contained in the open set and containing the given point). In other words, we have literally reduced our daunting task to the case where $M,N$ are shrinked to chart-domains.
2. the theorem holds for a map if and only if it holds for any map obtained by composing on the domain and target by diffeomorphisms.
3. by putting statements (1) and (2) together, it suffices to prove the theorem for $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$, which is a map between open subsets. This is why you can reduce to the case that $M\subset \Bbb{R}^m,N\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ are open.
4. by using (2) again, we can compose the domain and target by translations (since they’re diffeomorphisms). This allows us to reduce to the case that $F(0)=0$.
5. using (2) again, we can compose the domain and target by linear isomorphisms (i.e row/column reduction), which are of course diffeomorphisms, and suppose furthermore $DF_{0_{\Bbb{R}^m}}(x)=(x,0_{\Bbb{R}^{n-m}})$.

Now, step (5) is the case that you prove things in, because we have cleaned up all the distracting garbage. But as explained by steps (1)-(4), proving step (5), which at first glance seems like a special case, is sufficient to deduce the general case.